# Fake object that is created by a method, not a constructor

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, nsubstitute

I am trying to unit test code that uses an API, so I am trying to decouple.

I have created an interface for the "Application" class inside the API, which is sealed.

I then created a class that uses the interface which has one method that returns an "Application" type object.

Here is where I am having trouble, in my unit test I try to create an "Application" object to verify if the return value is correct. However the "Application" class does not have any constructors, nothing public or private(I checked with reflection). The object is created by calling static Application.Connect(AnotherTypeFromAPI arg), which returns an Application object.

How do I return a fake object that I cannot create?

```
appMock.Connect(arg).Returns("How do I return an Application object here?"));
```

Or am I going about this the wrong way in regards to unit testing code that relies on an API? The entire API relies on the "Application" type so if I cannot fake it, I am not sure yet how I can stub or mock the other methods I need.

I am using C#, NUnit, NSUbstitute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't normally mock or fake static methods such as `Application.Connect`. Just partition the code under test so that it takes an already created `IApplication` object.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because initially I was going down the path of testing the API, which isn't my code. What I did was create my own class that uses the API. That way I can stub the methods in the class I created to verify a call to the third party library happened. Partitioning allows me to stub out the API so I can test my code.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved but you're using the wrong pattern. Instead of exposing an instance of the Application via a new interface, you need to create an interface that **fully replaces** the concrete dependency.

### What you have

If I understand your question correctly, you have a sealed Application class that has some methods your program needs to be able to call, and it has no public constructor, only a static factory method. Here is a simple example for discussion, with only one method, `SomeMethod()`.

```
public sealed class Application
{
    //private ctor prevents anyone from using new to create this
    private Application()   
    {
    }

    //Here's the method we want to mock
    public void SomeMethod(string input)
    {
        //Implementation that needs to be stubbed or mocked away for testing purposes
    }

    //Static factory method
    static public Application GetInstance()
    {
        return new Application();
    }
}
```

### What you tried

What you did might look like this:

```
interface IApplication
{
    Application Application { get; }
}

class ApplicationWrapper : IApplication
{
    protected readonly Application _application;

    public ApplicationWrapper()
    {
        _application = Application.GetInstance();
    }

    public Application Application
    {
        get { return _application; }
    }
}
```

So that in your main code, you do this:

```
var a = new ApplicationWrapper();
a.Application.SomeMethod("Real argument");
```

That approach will never work for unit testing, because you still have a direct dependency on the sealed Application class. You've just moved it. You still need to call `Application.SomeMethod()`, which is a concrete method; you are supposed to depend only on the interface, not anything concrete.

### What would work

In theory, the "right" way to do this is to **wrap everything**. So instead of exposing `Application` as a property, you keep it private; instead, you expose wrapped versions of the methods, like this:

```
public interface IApplication
{
    void SomeMethod(string input);
}

public class ApplicationWrapper : IApplication
{
    protected readonly Application _application;

    public ApplicationWrapper()
    {
        _application = Application.GetInstance();
    }

    public void SomeMethod(string input)
    {
        _application.SomeMethod(input);
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
var a = new ApplicationWrapper();
a.SomeMethod("Real argument");
```

Or in a full class with DI, it would look like this:

```
class ClassUnderTest
{
    protected readonly IApplication _application; //Injected

    public ClassUnderTest(IApplication application)
    {
        _application = application; //constructor injection
    }

    public void MethodUnderTest()
    {
        _application.SomeMethod("Real argument");
    }
}
```

### How to unit test

In your unit test, you can now mock the IApplication with a new class, e.g.

```
class ApplicationStub : IApplication
{
    public string TestResult { get; set; }  //Doesn't exist in system under test

    public void SomeMethod(string input)
    {
        this.TestResult = input;
    }
}
```

Notice this class has absolutely no dependency on Application. So you no longer need to call `new` on it, or call its factory method, at all. For unit testing purposed, you just need to ensure it gets called properly. You can do this by passing in the stub and checking the `TestResult` afterward:

```
//Arrange
var stub = new ApplicationStub();
var c = ClassUnderTest(stub);

//Act
c.MethodUnderTest("Test Argument");

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(stub.TestResult, "Test Argument");
```

It's a bit more work to write the full wrapper (especially if it has a lot of methods), but you can generate a lot of that code with reflection or with third party tools. And it allows you full unit testing, which is the whole idea behind switching to that `IApplication` interface to begin with.

### TLDR:

Instead of

```
IApplication wrapper = new ApplicationWrapper();
wrapper.Application.SomeMethod();
```

you should use

```
IApplication wrapper = new ApplicationWrapper();
wrapper.SomeMethod();
```

to remove the dependency on the concrete type.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I started down this path, but the method takes another object from the API as an argument which also uses a factory method to create an object instance. And it was getting to the point where I would of had to wrap a large portion of the API. Also I realized I was beginning to test the API itself, rather than my code.